# A Riddle Within a Riddle

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, enigmatic-puzzle, steganography

> <sup>***M***</sup><sup>***Y***</sup> <sup>**f**</sup>riend, y**our** *l*uck h*as* ***T***urned.
>
> i*'*ve made t**H**<sup>**I**</sup>s <sup>R</sup>iddle and it i<sup>***s***</sup> the bes<sup>**t**,</sup> anD "s<sup>*o*</sup>on iT s**H**ould b**E** solved.
>   i*f* i***t*** is <sup>n</sup>ot, th*e*n a QU<sup>**I**</sup>et mi*Nd* **m**igh<sup>T</sup> let s**E**ed<sup>S</sup> be **S**<sup>*own*,</sup> with**i**n *wh*ich id*E*as ca***N*** g<sup>r</sup>ow.
>   in essen**C<sup>E</sup>**: <sup>a</sup>t **THE** end, in one sma<sup>ll</sup> **da<sup>y</sup>**, seCRet<sup>l</sup>***y***, ***<sup>O</sup>u***r <sup>v</sup>ie**W** r<sup>**e**</sup>garding the <sup>*s*</sup>olution caN be <sup>*t*O</sup>ld.
>
> *a**r***e you F**es***t*oon<sup>***i**n*</sup>g the Place wi*th* str*E*a*m*ers already
>
> this is a <sup>qu*i***R**</sup>ky, Fun, <sup>**E**</sup>xciting ri*d**d**le<sup>**.**</sup>*
>   by <sup>***my***</sup> CounT, the **f**ew g**Ift**ed *w**h**O* ca<sup>N</sup> solve are > to*l*<sup>*e*</sup>rable*,* BUt the te<sup>xT,</sup> inc. punct. **mark**s, is **S**PL<sup>*In*</sup>Tered <sup>a</sup>nD somehOW i<sup>N</sup> *revers*e.
>   many m<sup>a</sup>y fail, b<sup>u**T**</sup> t**H*E*** <sup>o</sup>ne<sup>*,*</sup> the disCErniNg <sup>w</sup>ill **T**ake h*<sup>**i**</sup>s* ti**m**e; wi<sup>ll</sup> R**Et*h***INk wh**aT** *o*ne *W*ord ma*y* or may n*O*t be rEQ*u*ested.
>
> i*f* y*oU* are a<sup>bl</sup>e, c<sup>**A**</sup>Ll a f**r**iend, l**o**SE the la<sup>**Ck**</sup> of <sup>**e**</sup>xciTeme<sup>*n*</sup>t, Inclu*d*e ***t**h*e r<sup>***i***</sup>ght a<sup>n</sup>***s***we*r*, and <sup>**f*i***</sup>nd the wo<sup>**r**</sup>*d* that solv<sup>**e**</sup>s the rid***d**l*e at ONc*e*.  yeS  ;<sup>***>***</sup>

---

- The solution to this puzzle is a single word.
- An explanation of how you arrived at the solution is required.
- There is more than one part to this puzzle.
- Paying attention to the tags might help (a little).
- If you're having trouble seeing the intricacies of the text, try zooming your browser.

Comment: Ooooh i**n**terest**i**ng **c**ryptic puzzl**e!** (This might be a hint?)

Comment: So many layers...

Comment: I really hope you didn't do all that formatting manually. If so, my sympathies.

Comment: @EngineerToast I did.  It took... a while.

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain Filtering through all the different ways of formatting is taking a while too.

Comment: @dcfyj Didn't want to make it too easy for you...  :P

Answer (score 55, accepted):

The final riddle, found by others is:

> <sup>My first, on its own, really loves to inquire.
>
>  My next, in an auto, will blacken in fire.</sup>
>  MY THIRD'S THE QUINTESSENCE; THE CROWN OF PERFECTION,
>  BUT SPLIT DOWN THE CENTRE IN TWO EQUAL SECTIONS.
>  **My fourth is the time since the day you were sired.
>
>  My fifth marks the time that a rocket is fired.**
>  *My last's often down when you start in the middle.
>
>  My whole, in reverse, is how you found this riddle.*

Which gives

> My first, on its own, really loves to inquire.  = **Y** (Its a question, why?)

> My next, in an auto, will blacken in fire.  = **H** (H in car makes char)

> My third's the quintessence; the crown of perfection,
>  but split down the centre in two equal sections.
>
>  Quintessence (the crown of perfection) = **PARAGON**
>  Split into two equal sections = remove central A, leaving two parts = **PARGON**

> My fourth is the time since the day you were sired.  = **AGE**

> My fifth marks the time that a rocket is fired.  = **T** (T-minus 10, 9, 8, ...)

> My last's often down when you start in the middle.  = **S** (for South, when starting in the middle of a map/compass, down = South)

> My whole, in reverse, is how you found this riddle.  Reverse YHPARGONAGETS

So the final answer is:

> **STEGANOGRAPHY**

which is indeed how

> the riddle was discovered, hiding in the text.  Very meta!  Well, not [Meta](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/) meta, but you know what I mean...

Comment: Ah, good point. Gotcha.

Comment: I guess no one noticed that the punctuation was actually coded into the puzzle as well.  I took the liberty of adding it to your answer.

Comment: Totally justified liberty, given the amount of effort it probably took to include it in the coding!

Comment: Well Played. xD

I don't think i would have gotten that, I presume the Paragon thing is a reference of some sort?

Comment: @ObviouslyJake Not really, just kind of the definition of paragon, with some poetic license.

Answer (score 13):

Partial Answer for time saving Sake.

Seeing as the whole actual riddle could be seen as slightly difficult to read with the subscript and misplaced capitals, I have done us the deed of making it nice and fresh.

---

My friend, your luck has turned.

I've made this riddle and it is the best, and "soon it should be solved.
If it is not, then a quiet mind might let seeds be sown, within which ideas can grow.
In essence: at the end, in one small day, secretly, our view regarding the solution can be told.

Are you festooning the place with streamers already

this is a quirky, fun, exciting riddle.
By my count, the few gifted who can solve are > tolerable, but the text, inc. Punct. Marks, is splintered and somehow in reverse.
Many may fail, but the one, the discerning will take his time; will rethink what one word may or may not be requested.

If you are able, call a friend, lose the lack of excitement, include the right answer, and find the word that solves the riddle at once. Yes ;>

---

My original workings out. (Didn't take much don't give me too much credit)

> The Superscript letters spell out: 
>
>  "My First on its own really loves to inquire. My next in an auto will blacken in fire"

Due to other answers by: (**@Sconibulus, @Yandrakus** and **@dcfyj**) I came to gather the **6** so far.

> My first on its own really loves to inquire. 
>
>  My next in an auto will blacken in fire 
>
>  MY THIRD THE QUINTESSENCE THE CROWN OF PERFECTION BUT SPLIT DOWN THE CENTRE IN TWO EQUAL SECTIONS
>
>  **My fourth is the time since the day you were sired** 
>
>  **My fifth marks the time that a rocket is fired** 
>
>  *My last's often down when you start in the middle. My whole,in reverse,is how you found this riddle>*

Now for my ideas for what they mean so far!

> "My first on its own really loves to **inquire**." 
>  I believe this to be the letter **Y**, a common abbreviation in text talk and speech sound, of the word '**why**' which is to question, to inquire.
>  
>  
>
>  For the **third point**, it mentions a crown, split down the middle.... I believe this has to do with the look of a **Capital** letter, seeing as it was derived from a sentence created from capitals. 
>  All the current letters that can be cut in half equally when capitalised are as follows, in order: 
>  `A H I M O T U V W X Y` - as well as the numbers `8` and `0`, though i feel we can exclude numbers.

Comment: Fixed it, thanks for the info. I had assumed that was what a markup was, seeing as it is up, above the text.

Comment: You have the last word(s) wrong

Comment: Ah. Entire should in fact be in tire. Thanks for that.

Comment: it's not a t, it's an f

Comment: oh god.... my eyes are lacking. Time for a check up soon, I think.

Answer (score 9):

Here are the italics:

> My last's often down when you start in the middle. My whole, reversed,is how you found this riddle>

Comment: Actually you spelled it correctly I think xD

Comment: Look in the middle of the word "splintered".

Comment: should it in stead be 'my whole in reverse is... etc?

Answer (score 8):

I found with the capital letters:

> MY THIRD THE QUINT ESSENCE THE CROWN OF PERFECTION BUT SPLIT DOWN THE CENTRE IN TWO EQUAL SECTIONS

In italics:

> My last's often down when you start in the middle. My whole, reversed,is how you found this riddle> thx to @dcfyj for clarification haha

Comment: I have a feeling you put up the italics while I was working on them haha. oh well.

Comment: Sorry bout that hahaha, really interested in know the word behind all this

Answer (score 7):

The bolded spell out

> My fourth is the time since the day you were sired
> My fifth marks the time that a rocket is fired

I believe these are

> 'a' and 't' respectively, but I'm much less certain about a.

The Capital Letters spell out

> My third the quintessence the crown of perfection 
>  but split down the centre in two equal sections

Not sure what this one is yet.